# Prove the Fibonacci numbers using mathematical induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove the identity $F_{n+2} = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^n F_i$ using mathematical induction and using the Fibonacci numbers.

Attempt: The Fibonacci numbers go (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...) so it can be seen that starting at the 3rd element is the same as starting at the beginning and adding one.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $F_{n+3}=\color{red}{F_{n+2}}+F_{n+1}=\color{red}{1+\sum_{i=0}^{n} F_i} +F_{n+1}=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} F_i$

Answer (score 1):

With

$F_0 = 0 \tag 1$

and

$F_1 = 1, \tag 2$

we define the Fibonacci sequence recursively by

$F_{n + 2} = F_{n + 1} + F_n; \tag 3$

furthermore, with

$F_2 = F_1 + F_0 = 1, \tag 4$

we see the identity

$F_{n+2} = 1 + \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n} F_i \tag 5$

holds in the case $n = 0$.  If we make the inductive hypothesis

$F_{k + 2} = 1 + \displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^k F_i, \tag 6$

then using (3) we find

$F_{k + 3} = F_{k + 2} + F_{k + 1} = 1 + \displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^k F_i + F_{k + 1} = 1 + \displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^{k + 1} F_i; \tag 7$

this completes the induction and establishes (5) for all $n$.